# How to close child form (if it is activated) from parent from in C#

Tags: c#, forms, parent

I have three form in C#, main form is A, second is B & third is C. I want to close B & C both form (if B & C are activated) from main form using a button.

How could I do that?

Comment: If you have variable that keeps the reference to The form objects, try to invoke its .close() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Form2 f2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
        Form3 f3 = (Form3)Application.OpenForms["Form3"];
        f2.Close(); f3.Close();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ne)
    { 
        //One of the forms is not opened
    }
}
```

or

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f is Form2)
        {
            //Form2 is activated. Close it
            f.Close();
        }
        if (f is Form3)
        {
            //Form3 is activated. Close it
            f.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an exception "System.NullReferenceException" when I run the first example of code at f.Close() line. I don't know why, but it doesn't call the catch statement. I tried the second one but it's not what I want. I also tried an in-built try-catch function but the error occurred again. Could you tell me why is it happening?

Comment: And, there's a continue button(in my IDE, Visual Studio 2019). When that button is pressed, the program ignores the exception and continues. Then the catch statement/function is called. So, why is the catch function calling after the exception is thrown and then ignored?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using WinForms you just need to call the `Close()` method on B and C.

```
public partial class FormA : Form
   {
      FormB formB;
      FormC formC;

      public FormA()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void BtnOpenChilds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         this.formB = new FormB();
         this.formC = new FormC();

         formB.Show();
         formC.Show();
      }

      private void BtnClosChilds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         this.formB.Close();
         this.formC.Close();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that the original OP did not state MDI Children and to clarify , all forms opened from the main form are technically child forms so I believe the OP did know what it meant.

Here is my alternative way to close all forms without getting the collection was modified error

```
        Form[] formsList = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x => x.Name == "FormB" || x.Name == "FormC").ToArray();
        foreach (Form openForm in formsList)
        {                
            openForm.Close();
        }
```

Be sure to have the Linq using

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        private Form3 form3;
         private Form2 form2;   

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();
             form3 = new Form3();
            form3.ShowDialog();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.Close();
            form3.Close(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this really is an MDI scenario:

```
foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
    frm.Close();
```

Comment: I didn't see where the OP said the forms where were MDIChildren??

Comment: The explicit use of the word "child" suggests that either it's MDI, or the OP doesn't know what it means.  Regardless, down vote for that?  Please....

Comment: I'm sure the OP doesn't know the meaning of *child*. The body suggests so. If you edit your answer, I'll remove my downvote

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn - you clearly misunderstand the usefulness of the down vote.  I will _not_ edit a perfectly useful answer just because you don't like it.  Down voting just to make your own answer stand out is childish.

Comment: Why would I down vote to make my own answer *stand out*?. There is an answer with +1, Why didn't I down vote that to bring it to 0 *to make my answer stand out*?. Why didn't I down vote the other answers *to make my answer stand out*. I down voted because your answer doesn't answer the question.